# How to get T* from T, T& or T* template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, reference

I am trying to find a way to get the base class of a template parameter.

Consider the following class:

```
template <class C>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(){};
        ~Foo(){};
        C* ptr;
};
```

if **C** is a reference (e.g. *Test&*) then *ptr* is type C&*

But I need to get a pointer the base class whether C is a reference, a pointer or anything else.

- if **C** is **Test&** then *ptr* need to be **Test***,
- if **C** is **Test*** then *ptr* needs to be **Test***,
- if **C** is **Test** then *ptr* needs to be **Test***, etc.

Is there anyway to get the "base" class of C so I can create the pointer I need ?

Comment: What if `C` is `Test***` or `Test[1][2]`?  Or `Test const*`?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but check into (i.e. Google) partial template specialization for reference and pointer types.

Comment: Good books on this topic are: D. Vandevoorde, N.M. Josuttis "C++ templates. The complete guide" and Alexandrescu "Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied". These books contain huge examples like this and give a taste of template metaprogramming techniques like traits and strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [`std::remove_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference)?

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class C>
class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(){};
        ~Foo(){};
        std::remove_reference<C>::type *ptr;
};
```

Answer (score 8):

If you really need the underlying element type, you can use recursive applications of the removal type manipulation traits:

```
#include <type_traits>

// precv = pointer, reference, extents, const, and volatile
template <typename T>
struct remove_precv
{
    typedef typename std::remove_pointer<
            typename std::remove_reference<
            typename std::remove_all_extents<
            typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>::type>::type>::type type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct element_type_impl
{
    typedef typename element_type_impl<
            typename remove_precv<T>::type, T>::type type;
};

template <typename T>
struct element_type_impl<T, T>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct element_type
{
    struct null_type { };
    typedef typename element_type_impl<T, null_type>::type type;
};
```

For example, `element_type<int***[42]>::type` is `int`.

Comment: Instead of `remove_precv`, I think `std::decay` might work here too, as noted in Kerrek SB's answer.  I wasn't familiar with that manipulation trait, and I'm not quite sure what its behavior is.

Comment: decay will also transform arrays and function types which may not be desired (of course in the q we only have classes).

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
    typedef typename std::remove_pointer<typename std::decay<T>::type>::type C;
    // ...
};
```

`decay` removes references and CV-qualifications, and `remove_pointer` removes pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a little bit of template meta-programming, for example:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
struct unpoint {
  typedef T type;
};

template <typename T>
struct unpoint<T*> {
  typedef typename unpoint<T>::type type;
};

int main() {
  int *a;
  int **b;
  int ***c;
  int ****d;

  const std::type_info& t1=typeid(unpoint<decltype(a)>::type);
  const std::type_info& t2=typeid(unpoint<decltype(b)>::type);
  const std::type_info& t3=typeid(unpoint<decltype(c)>::type);
  const std::type_info& t4=typeid(unpoint<decltype(d)>::type);
  assert(t1 == t2);
  assert(t1 == t3);
  assert(t1 == t4);
}
```

Where the specialisation of `unpoint` removes the pointer and recursively calls itself until there are no pointers left in the type.